# How to remember data of the client?

Tags: node.js, express

I have some information that is unique to each client. This is not the login information but just some generic data of the client - for example, say the address of the client.

Now, when a client connects with the server for the first time, I will read the address of the client.

Subsequently, each time the client makes requests to the server, I would like to use the address that I read from the first request.

How do I do this? I mean, how do I store some information on the client in the server itself so that with each request, I do not have to read the address again (from the DB) but instead read it directly from say, a global variable or a like a request header or something on those lines... How, do I attach the address to each client so that for future requests from the client, I can directly read the address information from the client's request itself without having to query the DB once more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit - this requires Express, didn't notice that your question was not tagged express. if you aren't using express you may want to look at the [`connect.session` example](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/examples/session.js), this is what express uses behind the scenes to populate `req.session`.

---

Depending on exactly what you want to do with the data, you might prefer to use `req.session` to store temporary information until the client closes the window or their cookie times out. Here's an example that keeps track of the address across future requests:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.logger());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.bodyParser());      
app.use(express.session({secret:'$tackoverflow-rules'}));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  if(req.session.address === undefined){
    res.send(200,'<html><body><form action="address" method="post">'
      +'<input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Enter address">'
      +'</form></body></html>');
  } else {
    res.send(200,'<html><body><span>I know that you live at '+req.session.address+'!</span></body></html>');
  };
});

app.post('/address', function(req, res){
  if(req.body.address !== undefined && req.body.address !== ""){
    req.session.address = req.body.address;
    res.redirect('/');
  } else {
    req.session.address = undefined;
    res.redirect('/');
  };
});

require('http').createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

Comment: I am using express. Updated post to include tag. Will check this out and get back...

Answer (score 0):

You can store the information in cookies or localStorage if the data is being displayed on a webpage. If you are using a jsp or php I would store it in a session. What client are you using?

Comment: Frontend is a web application built in AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global object with a clients address as the key that stores info:

```
var client = {}
//on connect
client[clientID] = {address: clientAddress} //so on

//To access
client[clientID].address; //or whatever you need
```

This is how I store client specific information with `socket.io`

Comment: Is this the best practice? I am a little bit skeptical since it is a global object...

Comment: You could always make it it's own Object instance, then define custom methods via prototype, but the above should do as well. Just be sure that on disconnect you remove the client from the object, else it may get out of control.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is small you can assign the data to a cookie and that way it will be passed back and forth on each request to the server (Localstorage will allow it to keep it on the client but it will NOT be be passed again to the server on the next request)

You can keep a collection in memory with this data on the server and look it up as @tymeJV indicated but this will only works if you have the data is not too big and if you run in a single server. As soon as the data grows you might run out of memory. Also if the server restarts you'll loose this information. As soon as you add a second server this approach will not work because you'll need to make sure the client connects to the same server (which I guess you could do with sticky sessions)

You might want to look into caching this data with something like Redis or another fast database like MongoDB for this kind of session information. That way you'll have a central store for it that could be optimized for performance so your site does not get bogged down while checking for this information.